# Create a temporary table and a column with calculated data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with four fields: ID, DATE, DESCRIPTION, AMOUNT.
I need to find the BALANCE, the sum of the amount of the row, with the sum of all rows until than.
To create the temp table I do:

`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS add_balance SELECT * FROM original_table`

My first question:
how can I add one column - "BALANCE" to this temp table.
Second question: to that column I want to insert:
SUM of the rows until then so that it can give the current balance in each row.

Comment: Replace `SELECT * FROM original_table` with a query that returns the table with the running sums as an additional column. If you're using MySQL 8.x you can use a window function to get the sums. If not, use a user variable. Don't forget to specify `ORDER BY date`.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer the first question like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS add_balance SELECT ID, DATE, DESCRIPTION, AMOUNT, [...] BALANCE FROM original_table
```

Where [...] you provide the formula that is to define the BALANCE value fields.

Comment: This does it in part, as you said. Now the question is what is the "formula"? If I do like a SUM(AMOUNT) it's giving me the whole sum in all the rows. Perhaps if I do a insert into the BALANCE column in a loop will work. I just don´t know how to make this loop, or another "formula".